# Trying to get isMultiple to execute properly

Tags: java

this executes, however it returns all answers as positive "8 is a multiple of 15" even if it is false. Not sure what I'm not seeing.

Here is what i have:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Multiples {

public static void main(String [] args){

    boolean run = true;

    while(run = true){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter one number:");
    int num1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a second number:");
    int num2 = input.nextInt();

    boolean result = isMultiple(num1,num2);


    if(result = true){
        System.out.println(num2 + " is a multiple of " + num1);
    }

    else{
        System.out.println(num2 + " is not a multiple of " + num1);
    }

    System.out.println("Do you want to enter another pair(y/n)?");
    String a = input.next();

    if(YesOrNo(a)){
       break;
    }

    }

}

    public static boolean YesOrNo(String a){

        if(a.equals("y"))
            return false;
        else if(a.equals("n"))
            return true;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public static boolean isMultiple (int x , int y){

         if(x % y == 0 || y % x == 0)
             return true;   
         else
             return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely a duplicate, for using `if (result = true)` instead of `if (result == true)`. When of course the best way to write would have been simply `if (result)`...

Answer (score 1):

```
if(result = true){
```

replace with

```
if(result == true){
```

(or simply)

```
if(result){
```

You are assigning it instead of comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition...

```
if (result = true) { ... }
```

...is an assignment.  The assignment returns the assigned value which is true.  So it will always resolve to true.

You can..

- use the equality operator (`==`)
- use the variable itself (since it is a boolean)
- use the result of the method as the condition (since you never reuse the variable)

These should produce the correct result

```
if (result == true) { ... }

if (result) { ... }

if (isMultiple(num1,num2)) { ... }
```

Answer (score -2):

**For the t/f:**

```
if (x % y == 0 || x % y == 1)
```

Comment: Your answer is not terribly clear. Are you saying that the `if` statement in method `isMultiple` (of class `Multiples` from the code in the question) is wrong? If so, then maybe you can [edit] your answer and explain why it is wrong and how your code fixes it? By the way, I recommend that you take the [tour] and also read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)